# When localisation preserves isomorphy of homotopy groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, bousfield-localization

Let $E$ be a generalized cohomology theory. Let's agree that $E$ satisfies property $(*)$ if for any two finite CW complexes with isomorphic homotopy groups their $E$-localizations also have isomorphic homotopy groups. Is there some non-tautological condition implying property $(*)$?

Comment: The only localization I know with this property is rationalization, and of course there is for trivial reasons.

Comment: @AknazarKazhymurat There is a variant of p-localization/completion for non simply connected spaces, but I doubt it has the property in question (I'm not 100% sure what it does to the fundamental group, but it is quite destructive)

Answer (score 5):

The question is very unlikely to have a satisfactory answer in the level of generality asked. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the two spaces with isomorphic homotopy groups, and let $LX$ and $LY$ denote their localizations with respect to $E$. For certain generalized cohomology theories $E$, we have formulas for $\pi_n(LX)$ and $\pi_n(LY)$, *if $X$ and $Y$ are nilpotent*, going back to Bousfield's paper [The localization of spaces with respect to homology](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938375900233). An [excellent summary](https://www3.nd.edu/~wgd/Dvi/Localizations.pdf) is provided by Dwyer, and teaches us, for example, that for $E = \mathbb{Z}/p$, one has $\pi_n(LX) \cong \pi_n(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$, and for any subring $R$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, taking $E = HR$ gives $\pi_n(LX) \cong \pi_n(X) \otimes R$. However, this is only with an assumption about $\pi_1(X)$ (i.e. that $X$ is simply connected, or at least nilpotent). Bousfield's 1997 paper [Homotopical Localizations of Spaces](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25098577) gets a similar result for nullification with respect to a Moore space (see Theorem 7.5).

A definitive modern treatment is the book [More Concise Algebraic Topology](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/TEAK/KateBookFinal.pdf) by May and Ponto. On page 395, it says "There are several different ways to generalize to non-nilpotent spaces, none of them well understood calculationally", and later on page 409 says "Little is known about the behavior on homotopy groups of localizations and completions of non-nilpotent spaces."

So, basically, if the OP restricts attention to nilpotent spaces and nicely behaved $E$, then everything should be fine, but it is extremely unlikely to get an answer for general $E$. For counterexamples of what can go wrong for specific $E$, you can look to work of Carles Casacuberta (e.g. Example 4.5 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7340), or the many examples and counterexamples [here](http://www.ub.edu/topologia/casacuberta/articles/Kortrijk.pdf)).

Comment: Another good reference is Farjoun's book: https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540606048